# object has no attribute 'logger'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I modified the `dictConfig` from this -

```
logconfig: dict = {
            'version': 1,
            'formatters': {
                'default': {
                    'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
                    'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
                }
            },
            'handlers': {
                'console': {
                    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                    'formatter': 'default'
                }
            },
            'loggers': {
                '': {  # root logger
                    'level': log_level,
                    'handlers': ['console']
                },
                'prm_example_agent': {  # Our module
                    'level': log_level,
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'propagate': False
                },
                'prm': {  # The PRM library
                    'level': log_level,
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'propagate': False
                }
            }
        }
```

to this - .

```
logconfig: dict = {
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
                'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default'
            },
            'file': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'default',
                'filename': '/tmp/log/ece_prm_app.log',
                'maxBytes': 1048576,
                'backupCount': 7
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {  # root logger
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console', 'file']
            },
            'prm_example_agent': {  # Our module
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'prm': {  # The PRM library
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console','file'],
                'propagate': False
            }
        }
    }
    logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
```

And I've started getting error on the codes where lines `self.logger.error` is mentoined. Could someone help me undestand where I'm wrong?

Comment: Does `logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)` throw any error? 
How about the `logging.getLogger()` call in your code? Does that throw any error?

Comment: @lllrnr101 Somehow the logging.getLogger() was removed. Thank you for giving a direction. Upon adding the line, error resolved.